# Convert string to array of arrays in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Want to 'simply' select the following `string` row (note that 'it is already' an array of arrays) to one of type `float[][]`

**From:**

`'[[1.1, 1], [2.2, 2]]'`

**To:**

`[[1.1, 1], [2.2, 2]]`

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply replace the brackets with braces, and you have the [string representation of the array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT), which you can cast to the desired data type.

```
SELECT CAST (replace(
                replace(
                   '[[1.1, 1], [2.2, 2]]', '[', '{'
                ), ']', '}'
             ) AS float[]
            );

      replace      
-------------------
 {{1.1,1},{2.2,2}}
(1 row)
```

Abelisto's version is even simpler:

```
SELECT translate('[[1.1, 1], [2.2, 2]]', '[]', '{}')::float[];
```

Here, `::` is the PostgreSQL shortcut for the standard `CAST` syntax.