# How to split array data to next row in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data in a table. I want to split the array data into separated rows.

```
create table test1 (
  _id serial, 
  questionId character varying (50), 
  answer character varying (50), 
  subquestionId character varying (50), 
  subquestionAnswer character varying (50), 
  isActive character varying (1)
);

INSERT INTO test1 (questionid,answer,subquestionid,subquestionanswer,isactive) 
values 
('question 1','true','[100,101,102]','[[true],[false],[true]]','1'),('question 2','false','[101,106]','[[false],[true]]','1');
```

| _id | questionid | answer | subquestionid | subquestionanswer | isactive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | question 1 | true | [100,101,102] | [[true],[false],[true]] | 1 |
| 2 | question 2 | false | [101,106] | [[false],[true]] | 1 |

**Output should be needed.**
[image]

Comment: `isActive` should be a `boolean` and `subquestionid` and `subquestionanswer`  should be normalized into a one-to-many relationship. But _at_ least those columns should be `text[]` or maybe combined into a single `jsonb` where the ID is the key and the flag is the value.

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input tables?

Comment: output is not available in the link. please share in the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66220840/4808122) you may convert the string representation of arrays to real arrays with translate and cast. (As commented you should **not** store the arrays as strings)

```
select 
   _id, 
   answer,
   translate(subquestionid, '[]', '{}')::int[] subquestionid,
   translate(subquestionanswer, '[]', '{}')::boolean[] subquestionanswer, 
   isactive
from test1;
```

result

```
_id|answer|subquestionid|subquestionanswer      |isactive|
---+------+-------------+-----------------------+--------+
  1|true  |{100,101,102}|{{true},{false},{true}}|1       |
  2|false |{101,106}    |{{false},{true}}       |1       |
```

To split the arrays use `unnest` and keep the order using `WITH ORDINALITY AS`

Finaly limit the result to rows with the identical `ordinality`, which I assume is the expected result, though differing from your output

```
with t as (
select 
   _id, 
   answer,
   translate(subquestionid, '[]', '{}')::int[] subquestionid,
   translate(subquestionanswer, '[]', '{}')::boolean[] subquestionanswer, 
   isactive
from test1
)  
select   
 t._id, 
 t.answer,
 a.subquestionid, 
 b.subquestionanswer,
 t.isactive
from t
cross join lateral unnest(subquestionid) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(subquestionid, nr)
cross join lateral unnest(subquestionanswer) WITH ORDINALITY AS b(subquestionanswer, nr)
where a.nr = b.nr


_id|answer|subquestionid|subquestionanswer|isactive|
---+------+-------------+-----------------+--------+
  1|true  |          100|true             |1       |
  1|true  |          101|false            |1       |
  1|true  |          102|true             |1       |
  2|false |          101|false            |1       |
  2|false |          106|true             |1       |
```

Comment: Getting error while data in below format.

insert query for new data.

INSERT INTO test1 (questionid,answer,subquestionid,subquestionanswer,isactive) 
values 
('question 3','true','[151,152,153,154]','[["option1"],["option1"],["option1","option2"],["option3"]]','1');

Comment: This is worth a new question along with the explanation what do you expect as an output for 153 - one or two lines? @Srk

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `string_to_array` to convert string to array, and generate multiple rows from single one as follows :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT t._id, t.questionid, t.answer, REGEXP_REPLACE(theAnswer, '\[|\]|\[\[|\]\]', '') as subquestionanswer, t.isactive
  FROM   test1 t, 
       unnest(string_to_array(subquestionanswer, '],[')) theAnswer
  ) S
```

this how it should be :

```
SELECT t._id, t.questionid, t.answer, s.subquestionid, t.subquestionanswer, t.isactive
FROM (
  SELECT _id, questionid, answer, REGEXP_REPLACE(subquestionans, '\[|\]|\[\[|\]\]', '') as subquestionanswer, isactive,
  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
           ORDER BY _id
        )
  FROM   test1, 
       unnest(string_to_array(subquestionanswer, '],[')) subquestionans
) t
inner join (
  SELECT _id , REGEXP_REPLACE(subquestion, '\[|\]', '') as subquestionid,
  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
           ORDER BY _id
        )
  FROM  test1 , 
       unnest(string_to_array(subquestionid, ',')) subquestion
) s on s.ROW_NUMBER = t.ROW_NUMBER;
```

Demo here : https://dbfiddle.uk/b1w3RyCJ

Comment: Well, unnest does guarantee to preserve the order, but the the join with the unnested table not, so for larger example you may get messed with the order of the rows in the `row_number` (`with ordinaltiy` was invented for this purpose - see the other answer)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply!

Below table data needs to convert into screenshot format. Earlier there was one bracket one value, now there are one bracket two values. (subquestionid-153). I have extract this data from Talend.

```
create table test1 (_id serial, questionId character varying (50), answer character varying (50), subquestionId character varying (50), subquestionAnswer character varying (225), isActive character varying (1));

INSERT INTO test1 (questionid,answer,subquestionid,subquestionanswer,isactive) values ('question 1','true','[100,101,102]','[[true],[false],[true]]','1'),('question 2','false','[101,106]','[[false],[true]]','1');
```

[image]